# How to remove auto-incremented ids from url (old url able to work fine for some time)?

Tags: .htaccess, security, url

In our web site we currently have url based on id which is `auto incremented`. Something like this

```
....../flats/{id} //here id is auto-incremented
```

But due to this competitors are `stealing our information` from our web-site. So we have decided to `encode id`.

But `problem` in this approach is if someone has bookmark(we also have shared url for advertising and etc.) our urls(old urls), they can not get information(actual users).

So what can we do so that we can remove auto incremented ids from url so competitors can not steal our data but actual user can get data.

**Approach**

For some period do the `permanent redirect of old urls to new one`.

`Problem in this approach` is that for that some time competitors can still able to get data.(they run loop on old urls and we redirect that url to new one, so no benefit of creating new urls).

Any suggestion how can we remove auto-incremanented ids from urls, but old url will still works.

Thanks.

Comment: did you know the IP address of competitors, if so you can block it using .htaccess

Comment: I block IPs too, but they use different IP if we block some IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe whole website is not anonymous only and your real users have to sign in or at least they have the opportunity to do so.

In case someone requests auto-incremented id url pattern redirect him to sign in form and after successful sign in redirect him to new hashed id url pattern that matches the old one.